# Hide the Setup link with Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to hide the Setup link in Salesforce using Javascript based on user's ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. A few years ago you might have used a sidebar hack or hidden iframes, but today that's just not possible. If you need to remove access to Setup, do so properly by removing the "View Setup and Configuration" permission from the user's profile.